# Flutter-Firestore: get Document with know id from Collection Group Query

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Here's a scheme of the structure of my Firestore database

[image: My database]

Each company doc has a `users` collection

In my Flutter app, I need to retrieve a **User document** (like the one marked with the blue star). I know the `id` of this document, but I don't know under which company document it is located.

What's the fastest way to retrieve such document? Can I use `.collectionGroup()` and then filter the query by the `doc id`?

Comment: Perhaps, this article [How to query collections in Firestore under a certain path?](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-query-collections-in-firestore-under-a-certain-path-6a0d686cebd2) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collectionGroup()` query with a `where()` clause.

```
Firestore.instance.collectionGroup('users').where('userIdField', isEqualTo: 'USER_ID')
```

You can read the user's company ID from the [DocumentReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html) of that fetched document.

As @Frank commented, using where with document ID in a collection group query will not match. You would have to store user's UID as a field as well.

Comment: Are you sure this works? For collection groups the index stores the full path of the document in the `documentId` field, so that wouldn't match (just) the `USER_ID` value.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I missed that for sure.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way? Like checking if `USER_ID` is contained `documentId`?

Comment: @GBerga it'll be best to store it as a field.